# How to calculate the same accumulated amount

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, strcmp, nested-if

im trying a code to calculate accumulated/incremented amount of specific value.

```
for (int a=1; a<= qtydrink; a++)
{
cout << "enter drink name:"
cin.getline( drink, 15)
.......
if (strcmp(drink, "beer") == 0)
{
payment = 10.00;
.......
```

oke so one beer would cost 10$, but if the user input another beer, will it add or replace or something? i have an amount of 1.20 and user inputs it twice, amounting to 2.40 but in the output its just 2.20 sometimes.

i have 2 for loops. one for food and one for drinks. each time user can input different types of foods or drinks with different payments. i have to total up both food and drink's payment in the end plus tax.

please elaborate.

Comment: `strcmp(drink, "beer")` don’t use the C string functions in C++, use std::string!

Comment: @manni66 haha yes ive seen everywhere in the forums people use that but in my beginner class, im not yet taught to do this so im not quite familiar at all. just 'using namespace std;'

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher). std::string is foundation, C string functions are advanced.

Comment: @manni66 INMFT (its not my fault then). i would be accustomed to it if taught but guess not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that you are using `payment` as your output, that would be because you are setting the payment to be equal to 10.00, rather than incrementing it. To perform the increment, use `+=` instead of `=`

EDIT: Everything you need to know about operators can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

Comment: yes im just using payment as my output after totalling it up with another variable. explain more on how to use +=

Comment: `payment += 10` is the same as `payment = payment + 10`.

Comment: @KarlReid It's not always the same, we have to mention. For builtin types --yes, but for custom ones you should always check.

Comment: @iDamn as Karl said, to use +=, you just need to write payment += 10.00.
If this is the correct answer please select it as the answer :)

Comment: @Rhino1181 just tried it out and it worked wonders! thank you for that. cant believe my teacher didnt teach that first before assigning this work.